Editing the woocommerce checkout page "order notes" with new checkout block
How can I adapt the following code to make it compatible with the new checkout block?
function md_custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) 
{
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'Special notes';
    $fields['order']['order_comments']['label'] = 'Add your special note';

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'md_custom_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );


The new WooCommerce Checkout Block relies on React and JavaScript for rendering and customization. To extend its functionality, we need to use the WooCommerce Blocks Extensibility API.
Use below below script to Modify the order_comments Field in JavaScript-
import { useCheckoutExtensionRegistration } from '@woocommerce/blocks checkout';

// Modify order comments field for WooCommerce Checkout Block.
useCheckoutExtensionRegistration(
    'md-custom-checkout', // Unique identifier
    () => {
        wp.data.subscribe(() => {
            const checkoutStore = wp.data.select('wc/store/checkout');
            if (!checkoutStore) return;

            const fields = checkoutStore.getCheckoutFields()?.order || {};
            if (fields.order_comments) {
                wp.data.dispatch('wc/store/checkout').updateCheckoutFields({
                    order: {
                        ...fields,
                        order_comments: {
                            ...fields.order_comments,
                            placeholder: 'Special notes',
                            label: 'Add your special note',
                        },
                    },
                });
            }
        });
    }
);


Thanks, but trying your code as a JS or PHP code snippet in WordPress, I am getting a bunch of syntax error. Could you please review your script or am I doing something wrong?
